How to mount AARUF CD image?
I have a CD image file which has AARUF as its filename extension and I want to access its files.
Using file, I don't get any further information about the format:
$ file image.aaruf
image.aaruf: data
$ 

Trying to mount the image with fuseiso results in errors:

init: wrong standard identifier in volume descriptor 0, skipping..
init: wrong standard identifier in volume descriptor 1, skipping..
init: wrong standard identifier in volume descriptor 2, skipping..
init: wrong standard identifier in volume descriptor 3, skipping..
init: wrong standard identifier in volume descriptor 4, skipping..
init: wrong standard identifier in volume descriptor 5, skipping..
init: wrong standard identifier in volume descriptor 6, skipping..
init: wrong standard identifier in volume descriptor 7, skipping..



Apparently, the format of the AARUF file is called Aaru Image Format: https://github.com/aaru-dps/Aaru
I was able to use the binary from their GitHub releases page to convert the image to the CDRWIN image format:
$ wget https://github.com/aaru-dps/Aaru/releases/download/v5.3.2/aaru-5.3.2_linux_amd64.tar.gz
$ tar xvf aaru-5.3.2_linux_amd64.tar.gz
$ ./aaru image convert --force image.aaruf image.cue

The resulting image.bin can be mounted to access the image contents:
$ mkdir content
$ fuseiso image.bin content

Unmounting:
$ fusermount -u content

